# Extract work from correlations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-information, work

I'm studying the possible connection between correlations and thermodynamics work.

In particular, in this article: [Wormholes and the thermodynamic arrow of time](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.2.043095), I am struggling to find their equation (2.10) i.e

$$
W \leq I * \frac{T_1+T_2}{2}
$$

The extractable work is bounded by the mutual information times the mean temperature. I am interested in the case where the two correlated systems have different temperatures but for example they found exactly the same relation here :[Trade-off Between Work and Correlations in Quantum Thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06884) in the case of the same temperature.

What I have is: if my system is composed of two subsystems R and L, initially uncorrelated, and undergoes a transformation (that leads to the creation of correlation between R and L) such that the variation of free energy for each of the systems is positive:
$$
\Delta F_{R,L} = \Delta E_{R,L} \beta_{R,L} - \Delta S_{R,L} \geq 0
$$
Then the work that I can extract is
$$W = \Delta F = \Delta F_R + \Delta F_L = \Delta E_{R} \beta_{R} - \Delta S_{R}+ \Delta E_{L} \beta_{L} - \Delta S_{L}\geq 0\\
$$

If someone is familiar with these articles or the connection between work and correlations, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what exactly happens in these articles, but intuitively the classical case seems quite trivial: two systems (e.g. oscillators, pendulums etc.) that are perfectly correlated move exactly the same, hence there can be no change in distance between them. One can not extract work from such a system. The max. work can be extracted from in case of perfect anti-correlation because it maximizes the displacement. In statistical mechanics we will additionally sum over all microstates to get the average work, won't we?